# Need assistance with basic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, erd

I was doing some exercises for practice and have a small problem with my query. 
My initial code is below. The problem is I am getting the wrong answer in the final column/

The question : a query to find out the total attributed sales to each sales person for all SalesOrders placed in 2008. Use the TotalDue of the orders to find the sales amounts and the SalesPersonID to find the sales person to attribute. E.g. SalesOrderID 43659 should be attributed to SalesPersonID 279.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT p.BusinessEntityID,p.FirstName,p.LastName,  t.TotalDue
    FROM Person.Person p,Sales.SalesPerson s,Sales.SalesOrderHeader t
    WHERE p.BusinessEntityID = s.BusinessEntityID
```

Here is the image  of my ERD  http://www.2shared.com/photo/h2-jMQyP/AdventureWorks2008.html .

Comment: if possible please post some sample data with desired result.. so that it would be helpful to correctly says the query .. :)

Comment: Since you are learning, at least learn correctly, do not ever use implicit joins. They are a very poor programming techinique.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the ideal example of using the `GROUP BY` clause.

Try the following query:

```
select p.BusinessEntityID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, sum(t.TotalDue) as TotalDue
from Person.Person p
join Sales.SalesPerson s on p.BusinessEntityID = s.BusinessEntityID
join Sales.SalesOrderHeader t on t.BusinessEntityID = s.BusinessEntityID
where year(t.OrderDate) = 2008
group by p.BusinessEntityID, p.FirstName, p.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want totaldue made in 2008 you have to give one more condition for this year part

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.BusinessEntityID,p.FirstName,p.LastName,  t.TotalDue
FROM Person.Person p,Sales.SalesPerson s,Sales.SalesOrderHeader t
WHERE p.BusinessEntityID = s.BusinessEntityID 
and year(date_column) = '2008'
```

Comment: i am still not getting the sales column wrong this is what i had

SELECT p.BusinessEntityID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, s.TotalDueFROM Person.Person p, Sales.SalesOrderHeader sWHERE p.BusinessEntityID = s.SalesPersonID AND YEAR(OrderDate) = '2008';.

Comment: I think this query returns a cartesian product between `Person`/`SalesPerson` on on side and `SalesOrderHeader` on the other. That's because there's no join condition with the `SalesOrderHeader` table.

Comment: -1 for user of implicit joins and for not recognizing the accidental cross join as a result.

Comment: @HLGEM accept your point ... but see as what I was trying to say is to add year part while checking/ extracting data . ..